# Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ragefacefolks/com.example.ragefacefolks.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-intent

Today is my first day with java. I can not figure out the reason of this error.

MainActivity.java is like this below

```
package com.example.ragefacefolks;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.app.Activity;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    Button bMain = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    @Override
    public void registerForContextMenu(View view) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.registerForContextMenu(bMain);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
            ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu);

    }


}
```

wont be hard for you guys to know its reaon. Need a little help. 
log cat is showing these results

```
09-27 07:59:24.677: D/AndroidRuntime(555): Shutting down VM
09-27 07:59:24.677: W/dalvikvm(555): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
09-27 07:59:24.707: E/AndroidRuntime(555): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-27 07:59:24.707: E/AndroidRuntime(555): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ragefacefolks/com.example.ragefacefolks.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-27 07:59:24.707: E/AndroidRuntime(555):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1569)
09-27 07:59:24.707: E/AndroidRuntime(555):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
09-27 07:59:24.707: E/AndroidRuntime(555):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
09-27 07:59:24.707: E/AndroidRuntime(555):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
09-27 07:59:24.707: E/AndroidRuntime(555):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-27 07:59:24.707: E/AndroidRuntime(555):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-27 07:59:24.707: E/AndroidRuntime(555):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
09-27 07:59:24.707: E/AndroidRuntime(555):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1):

This

```
Button bMain = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

Should be in `onCreate` after `setContentView`. You initialize it outside of any method

```
private Button bMain;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    bMain = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
}
```

Comment: you beat me by 8 seconds!

Comment: Thankyou, Raghunadan. I knew it was a newbie question. :)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call:

```
Button bMain = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

in the class like that (specifically, cannot be called before `onCreate`).

Move this code to `onCreate`.

Answer (score 1):

Remove line

```
Button bMain = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

and change `onCreate` method.-

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button bMain = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    registerForContextMenu(bMain);
}
```

There's no need to override `registerForContextMenu` method.